# Can't load properly CSS in the JSX

Tags: css, webpack

I've configured my webpack config with 3 loaders, babel, css and file

Everything is working properly, I can import in the JSX files my own created CSS files and it's bundled fine by the ExtractTextPlugin!

My problem is that for third party modules, like for example bootstrap, I can't import the CSS in  a easy way.

```
import "./style/app.css" //works
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" //crashes
import "css-loader!bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" //works
```

Why for third party modules, it doesn't identifies my loader config? Due to that reason it's not being exported by the ExtractTextPlugin.

If I try to import inside the app.css like this:

```
@import url("~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css")
```

That way it's properly imported by the loader.

One additional detail, is that the bootstrap css loads some additional fonts. If I import trough the @import the file-loader is triggered as expected!

But, if I try to use the css-loader! in the JSX, it works partially because it imports the CSS but can't handle the fonts, so the file-loader isn't being triggered!

Comment: Crashes? How? Error message?

Comment: Hello, if i try to import by JSX without css-loader the error is the following: ERROR in ./~/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
Module parse failed: /Users/gquental/projects/react-redux-starter/node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css Unexpected token (5:83)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|  * Copyright 2011-2016 Twitter, Inc.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution!

The problem was in the loader, were I forgot to add the include property pointing to the node_modules!